# Creating New WebSphere cluster

Tags: java, cluster, websphere

I need to improve WAS perfomance and want to make cluster. I have two separate machines with WebSpphere 7 on it.

As I see to do this, I need to add node from my second (remote) WAS to the first one. 
I try to use "Add node" from console, but without success.

[image]

It can't find host when I try to execute it.

WAS help says about host: `Specifies the host name or IP address of the node to add to the cell. A WebSphere Application Server instance must be running on this machine.`

Does that mean that I cannot add node from a remote machine with "add node?"

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the steps of federating of a 2nd node into the DMGR of the 1st node are the following.

a.  Install WAS binaries on the 2nd node.
b.  Setup a app server profile on the 2nd node.
c.  Federate it into the DMGR of the 1st node.

How have you setup your 2nd node?

Answer (score 0):

Does your second node have a profile, and a running server or nodeagent running on it? You need it in order to the DMGR to being able to locate it an open a SOAP connection, to federate it.

Also remember to enter the correct SOAP port, as well as the user/password for the 2nd machine instance.